# Retrieve an evenly distributed number of elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know how to extract every nth item in an array, but what I have difficulties with is the following:

How can I extract every nth item from an array of 1800 elements, always including the first and the last element, up to a total of 256 elements?

Example:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Extract 5 elements:

```
extract = [1,3,5,7,10];
```

Comment: How are the rest 254 items are decided? At random? Does it matter at all? You could extract 255 first items and append the last one.

Comment: If you can give us enough information we can help you, otherwise we're guessing.

Comment: Or are the ones in the middle extracted on a "every nth" basis?

Comment: When you say extracting are you removing the elements from the array or just copying them? Also, in your example you aren't event retrieving the last element like you said.

Comment: If your `extract` array is the elements extracted from the original array, you didn't extract the last element. So it seems that result is not what you're looking for, since in according to your question you need to include the first and last items.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like this?

```
/**
 * Retrieve a fixed number of elements from an array, evenly distributed but
 * always including the first and last elements.
 *
 * @param   {Array} items - The array to operate on.
 * @param   {number} n - The number of elements to extract.
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function distributedCopy(items, n) {
    var elements = [items[0]];
    var totalItems = items.length - 2;
    var interval = Math.floor(totalItems/(n - 2));
    for (var i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        elements.push(items[i * interval]);
    }
    elements.push(items[items.length - 1]);
    return elements;
}
```

Example:

```
// Set up an array for testing purposes
var items = [];
for (var i=1; i<= 1800; i++) {
    items.push(i);
}

var extracted = distributedCopy(items, 256);

console.log(extracted);
```

Comment: just noticed that this is returning only 227 items instead of 256

Comment: @jokerstream Yes you are correct, there was a problem with rounding as the numbers get larger. Try the updated version.

Comment: WOW. This is exactly what i was looking for after a few hours of google searching.

Comment: Note that you're Math.floor'ing interval before the loop instead of inside every iteration (`Math.floor(rawInterval * i)`). So if interval is eg 1.8 (eg. picking 100 elems from 180-long array), actual interval will be 1, so you'll pick elements mostly from the first half of the array. I've added improved solution

Answer (score 7):

I slightly improved previous responses

```
function evenlyPickItemsFromArray<T>(allItems: T[], neededCount: number) {
  // if we want more items than avaliable, return all items
  if (neededCount >= allItems.length) {
      return [...allItems];
  }
  // buffer for collecting picked items
  const result: T[] = [];
  const totalItems = allItems.length;
  // default interval between items (might be float)
  const interval = totalItems/neededCount;

  for (let i = 0; i < neededCount; i++) {
    // always add half of interval, so 'picking area' is 'aligned' to the center
    // eg evenlyPickItemsFromArray([0...100], 1); // [50] instead of [0]
    const evenIndex = Math.floor(i * interval + interval / 2);

      result.push(allItems[evenIndex]);
  }
  return result;
}

// TESTING

// helper to create 0...n array
function createNLongArray(n: number) {
  return Array.from({length: n}).map((_, i) => i);
}

console.log(evenlyPickItemsFromArray(createNLongArray(100), 20)) // [2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57, 62, 67, 72, 77, 82, 87, 92, 97]

console.log(evenlyPickItemsFromArray(createNLongArray(200), 3)) // [33, 100, 166]
```

note it's not picking first/last elements every time as it's actually quite complex - eg. if I'm picking 1 elem - should I pick first or last etc. It's just finding even distribution and pick them. 1st and last will be picked only when you want all or almost all elements from the input array

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is to write

```
array.filter(filterFunc)
```

where `filterFunc` is called for each element with parameters of `elt`, `index`, and `array`, and should return `true` or `false` depending on whether you want to filter that element in or out.

So you need to write `filterFunc`. To do that, **you have to define it clearly in your mind**. For example, here's a function which creates a `filterFunc` depending on how many elements you want to extract:

```
function makeFilterFunc(howMany) {
  return function filterFunc(elt, idx, arr) {
    return idx === 0         ||       // first element
      idx === arr.length-1     ||       // last element
      idx % Math.floor(arr.length / howMany) === 0;
  };
}
```

Now

```
filterFunc = makeFilterFunc(256);
array.filter(filterFunc)

< Array[258]
```

Comment: Sometimes too close to threshold values

`var test = new Array(14).fill('a').map((item, i) => item + i)
test.filter(makeFilterFunc(3))`
// ["a0", "a4", "a8", "a12", "a13"] a12 and a13 too close

Answer (score -1):

Visual demonstration of the algorithm @pie6k
https://codepen.io/renderlife/pen/GRoxgZj

**HTML**

```
<h2>Original array</h2>
<div class="chart js-chartData"></div>
<h2>Evenly reduced array (saved element is green)</h2>
<div class="chart js-chartResult"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chart {
  background: #aaaebc;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.chart .bar {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: #d5d7de;
  margin: 2px;
  min-width: 5%;
  height: 50px
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}
.chart .bar.save {
  background: green;
}
```

**JS/JQuery**

```
elementsInArray = 365
neededCountElementsInArray = 234

function createNLongArray(n) {
  return Array.from({length: n}).map((_, i) => i + 1);
}

function evenlyPickItemsFromArray(allItems, neededCount) {
    if (neededCount >= allItems.length) {
        return [...allItems]
    }

    const result = []
    const totalItems = allItems.length
    const interval = totalItems / neededCount

    for (let i = 0; i < neededCount; i++) {
        const evenIndex = Math.floor(i * interval + interval / 2)
        result.push(allItems[evenIndex])
    }

    return result
}

array = createNLongArray(elementsInArray)
array.map(i => $('.js-chartData').append('<span class="bar">' + i + '</span>'))
elementsSave = evenlyPickItemsFromArray(array, neededCountElementsInArray)
console.log(elementsSave)

array.map(i => {
    if (elementsSave.includes(i)) {
      $('.js-chartResult').append('<span class="bar save">' + i + '</span>')
    } else {
      $('.js-chartResult').append('<span class="bar">' + i + '</span>')
    }    
  }
)
```