# Get the most number of strictly evenly spaced elements of an array up to 'N'

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, array-algorithms

I want to get *N* elements from an array, such that the elements are **evenly spaced** between each other. As a restriction, I also want the **first** and **last** elements to always be picked.

Other edge cases include:

- `N <= 2` which would simply return the first and last elements.
- `N >= Length` which would simply return the full array.

After looking around I came across several answers that solved this problem (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439437/retrieve-an-evenly-distributed-number-of-elements-from-an-array) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36983/take-an-array-and-return-n-elements-as-evenly-spaced-as-possible/56627)). And they work, but I realized I had more constraints that weren't addressed.

The answers presented are *loose* in the sense that if they're off-by-one, then it wouldn't be a big deal. In my case, it is, thus the term ***strict*** in the title.

For example, given L=6 and N=3, in loose form:
`A = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`
`R = [ 0, 2, 5 ]` or `R = [ 0, 3, 5 ]`

However, neither results are strictly evenly spaced as for L=6,N=3 such result is simply not possible.

What I am looking for is to **loose** the ***N*** variable. In other words, to decrement *N* to the closest number which makes the problem possible.
In the case of L=6,N=3, that number would be N=2 which would result in `R = [ 0, 5 ]`.

I could do a trial-and-error solution with the answers from the previously mentioned answers (simply testing and decrementing *N* by 1), but I'm trying to think of a more performant solution.

Last remark: I'm looking for ideas, and thus pseudo-code is completely fine! I am, however, going to implement it in Javascript, so please don't rely on other language-specific functionality.

Edit: The actual array elements might not be numbers (and there are no order guarantees).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It's an example, the actual values are not even numbers. Sorry, should have made that clear...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `Length` the valid values of `N` are equal to `fac+1`, where `fac` is a factor of `Length-1`.

First consider the edges cases: `1` and `Length-1` are obviously factors, which gives `N=2` and `N=Length`.

If `Length-1` is prime then these are the only options, as is the case with `Length=6` in the example you gave.

For `Length=7`, `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}`, factors are `(1,2,3,6)`, so options are `N=2,3,4,7`:

```
{0, 7}
{0, 3, 7}
{0, 2, 4, 7}
{0, 1, 2, 3 4, 5, 7}
```

So, for a given `Length` and `N`, determine the largest value `M` such that `M <= N` and `M-1` is a factor of `Length-1`. Something like this (Java) would work:

```
static int maxN(final int len, final int n)
{
    int maxN = n;
    while((len-1) % (maxN-1) != 0) 
        maxN -= 1;
    return maxN;
}
```

There may be more efficient approaches.